# Python get a random wall from rectangle in a 2d array

Tags: python

So i have a rectangle of this form:

```
class Rect:  # used for the tunneling algorithm
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.x1 = x
        self.y1 = y
        self.x2 = x + w
        self.y2 = y + h

    def center(self):
        center_x = (self.x1 + self.x2) // 2
        center_y = (self.y1 + self.y2) // 2
        return center_x, center_y

    def intersect(self, other):
        # returns true if this rectangle intersects with another one
        return (self.x1 <= other.x2 and self.x2 >= other.x1 and
                self.y1 <= other.y2 and self.y2 >= other.y1)
```

I've been trying to get any point off any wall (including corners) and pass it as an x, y value. The rectangle only has these values: the coordinates x and y, the width and height.

Normally for any type of 2d array to get all the values (including the corners even if they repeat) I would do this:

```
alist=[arr[0,:], arr[:,-1], arr[-1,:], arr[:,0]]
```

This will basically give me the values from which to pick but in this particular case i'm only working with  4 values and I'm not sure how to do this without having to recreate the whole rectangle 2d array.

Note that the whole rectangle is in a bigger array itself and the said coordinates are from there but I would like it as self contained as possible.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't exactly get what you want to achieve. Can you edit your question to provide us with a concrete example? Perhaps with an array and the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to produce all the integers coordinates of the rectangle, one way would be to implement the `__getitem__` method in your `Rect` class:

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    def iteritem(k, kmin, kmax):
        if isinstance(k, int):
            yield kmin + k if k >= 0 else kmax + k
        elif isinstance(k, slice):
            for i in range(k.start or kmin, k.stop or kmax, k.step or 1):
                yield i

    if isinstance(k, tuple) and len(k) == 2:
        result = []
        for i in iteritem(k[0], self.x1, self.x2):
            for j in iteritem(k[1], self.y1, self.y2):
                result.append((i, j))
        return result
```

That would produce any kind of coordinate ranges:

```
>>> r = Rect(10, 20, 5, 4)
```

top-left corner:

```
>>> r[0,0]
[(10, 20)]
```

bottom-right corner:

```
>>> r[-1,-1]
[(14, 23)]
```

top-row:

```
>>> r[0,:]
[(10, 20), (10, 21), (10, 22), (10, 23)]
```

all coordinates:

```
>>> r[:,:]
[(10, 20), (10, 21), (10, 22), (10, 23), (11, 20), (11, 21), (11, 22), (11, 23), (12, 20), (12, 21), (12, 22), (12, 23), (13, 20), (13, 21), (13, 22), (13, 23), (14, 20), (14, 21), (14, 22), (14, 23)]
```

border coordinates:

```
>>> r[0,:] + r[:,-1] + r[-1,:] + r[:,0]
[(10, 20), (10, 21), (10, 22), (10, 23), (10, 23), (11, 23), (12, 23), (13, 23), (14, 23), (14, 20), (14, 21), (14, 22), (14, 23), (10, 20), (11, 20), (12, 20), (13, 20), (14, 20)]
```

Comment: Both yours and @KyrSt's implementations are very helpful but I will have to chose this one as the best answer as it helps me get both coordinate pairs for each point in the chosen walls using a simple list comprehension method

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, what you essentially want is for example, if you have this 2d array

```
[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
 [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

And a rectangle that starts at (1,1) with width and height 3, then that rectangle is supposed to be:

```
 7  8  9
12    14
17 18 19
```

And by trying to get the walls, I suppose this means to extract `[7,8,9]`, `[7, 12, 17]`, `[9, 14, 19]` and `[17, 18, 19]` as lists.

With that in mind, your desired code simply has to select from the array those values that constitute a wall. The way you have defined your class, we can see that the cells of let's say the north wall, have `y1` as their first index and their second index goes from `x1` to `x2`. Accordingly, the cells of the east wall have their first index taking values from `y1` to `y2` and their second index is `x2`. And so on for the other walls.

In code, a quick solution would be the following:

```
class Rect:  # used for the tunneling algorithm
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.x1 = x
        self.y1 = y
        self.x2 = x + w - 1
        self.y2 = y + h - 1

    def get_wall(self, grid, wall_name):
        # `grid` is the 2d array, such as `grid[i][j]` element is in i-th row and j-th column
        # `wall_name` accepts 'east', 'west', 'north', 'south' as values

        if wall_name == 'west':
            wall = [grid[i][self.x1] for i in range(self.y1, self.y2+1)]
        if wall_name == 'east':
            wall = [grid[i][self.x2] for i in range(self.y1, self.y2+1)]
        if wall_name == 'north':
            wall = [grid[self.y1][i] for i in range(self.x1, self.x2+1)]
        if wall_name == 'south':
            wall = [grid[self.y2][i] for i in range(self.x1, self.x2+1)]

        return wall
```

(Note that I added -1 when computing y2 and x2 values. As I feel that if a square starts at 2 and has width=2 then it ends at 3 not at 4. But that's just a convention)

To run the code with the example I mentioned, you can add those lines:

```
grid = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

rect = Rect(1,1,3,3)

# The rectangle is:
#  *  *  *  *  *
#  *  7  8  9  *
#  * 12  * 14  *
#  * 17 18 19  *
#  *  *  *  *  * 

print(rect.get_wall(grid, 'north')) # will print [7,8,9]
print(rect.get_wall(grid, 'south')) # will print [17,18,19]
print(rect.get_wall(grid, 'east'))  # will print [9,14,19]
print(rect.get_wall(grid, 'west'))  # will print [7,12,17]
```

Finally, note that this code will fail if the rectangle is out of bounds with regard to the array. But you can easily solve it with a few simple if cases.